# SQL Query with non exists optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which i am directly executing in my Code & putting it in datatable. The problem is it is taking more than 10 minutes to execute this query. The main part which is taking time is `NON EXISTS`.

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId], 
    [t0].[InOutDate], 
    [t0].[InOutFlag], 
    [t0].[InOutTime] 
FROM [dbo].[MachineLog] AS [t0] 
WHERE 
        ([t0].[CompanyId] = 1) 
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] >= '2016-12-13')
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] <= '2016-12-14') 
    AND 
    (   NOT (EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] 
        FROM [dbo].[TO_Entry] AS [t1]  
        WHERE 
                ([t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId]) 
            AND ([t1]. [CompanyId] = 1) 
            AND ([t0].[PayrollEmployeeId] = [t1].[EmployeeId]) 
            AND (([t0].[InOutDate]) = [t1].[Entry_Date]) 
            AND ([t1].[Entry_Method] = 'M') 
        ))
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId], [t0].[InOutDate]
```

Is there any way i can optimize this query? What is the work around for this. It is taking too much of time.

[image]

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Write the exists part as the join and check the performance again

Comment: Could you also please share the execution plan? That will guide us for performance fix in fact

Comment: @Eralper Check is it the same plan that you wanted, i am less aware of SQL

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can convert the NOT EXISTS into a LEFT JOIN query with second table returning NULL values

Please check following SELECT and modify if required to fulfill your requirements

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId], [t0].[InOutDate], [t0].[InOutFlag], [t0].[InOutTime] 
FROM [dbo].[MachineLog] AS [t0] 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TO_Entry] AS [t1]
    ON  [t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId]
    AND [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId] = [t1].[EmployeeId]
    AND [t0].[InOutDate] = [t1].[Entry_Date]
    AND [t1]. [CompanyId] = 1
    AND [t1].[Entry_Method] = 'M'
WHERE 
        ([t0].[CompanyId] = 1) 
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] >= '2016-12-13')
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] <= '2016-12-14') 
    AND [t1].[EmployeeId] IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId], [t0].[InOutDate]
```

Comment: When i run this query it executes in 1 second. But only difference of total count of the result between old query & new query is 1 record. 
Old query takes more than 10 minutes - total count - 9109
.New query takes 1 second- total count - 9110

Comment: In fact you might need to add aditional criteria in WHERE clause. We only added t1.EmployeeId IS NULL from the LEFT JOIN condition.  BTW, I just realized that we had twice " [t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[PayrollEmployeeId] " in LEFT JOIN

Comment: I also noticed 1 thing. When i run my old query for date range bigger for e.g 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-20. Then the query runs less than a second. Only when i take smaller range, it is taking more than 40 seconds now after creating index.

Answer (score 2):

You will realize that there is an informative message on the execution plan for your query

It is informing that there is a missing cluster index with an effect of 30% on the execution time

It seems that transaction data is occurring based on some date fields like Entry time.
Dates fields especially on your case are strong candidates for clustered indexes. You can create an index on Entry_Date column
I guess you have already some index on InOutDate
You can try indexing this field as well

Comment: As i created index on `Entry_Date`, it takes only 30 seconds now.